# GetProcessesByName stops my events in outlook

Tags: c#, .net, process, outlook, outlook-addin

I wrote a program which syncs my Outlook calendar. So good so far the program works fine. But if Outlook crashes or gets restarted my program does need to fire "ThisAddin_Startup()" again to link to the new outlook instance. I tried so solve this by monitoring the running processes. But then it didn't work any more. If I call "Process.GetProcessesByName" in the loop nothing works it its commented then it does work.

Does anyone know why?

```
bool monitoring = false;
while (true)
{
   if (!monitoring) //Start monitoring or restart monitoring
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("start");
      ThisAddIn_Startup();
      monitoring = true;
   }
   Process[] outlook;
   outlook = Process.GetProcessesByName("blabla");
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}


private void ThisAddIn_Startup()
{
   _OutlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();

   //Link Inbodx Events
   _olFolderInbox.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);

   //Link Calendar Events
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Add);
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemRemove += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Deleted);
}
```

EDIT:
Simplified the hole code still nothing works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace OAddIn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Outlook.Application _OutlookApplication;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder _olFolderInbox;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder _olFolderCalendar;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder _olFolderCalendar_AddOnCalendar;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder _olFolderDeletedItems;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Thread osThread = new Thread(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            osThread.Start();

            Thread osThread2 = new Thread(CheckIfProcessIsRunning);
            osThread2.Start();
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup()
        {
            _OutlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
            InitCalendars();
            InitMailBox();

            Debug.WriteLine("Start Now Monitoring");

            //Link Inbodx Events
            _olFolderInbox.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);

            //Link Calendar Events
            _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Add);
            _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);
            _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemRemove += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Deleted);

        }

        void CheckIfProcessIsRunning()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                int returnValue = 0;
                Process[] o = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");

                Debug.WriteLine("FSSFSSGSFSFSFSFSFSF: " + returnValue);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }

        private void InitCalendars()
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder calendars = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)_OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            try
            {
                _olFolderCalendar_AddOnCalendar = calendars.Folders["AddOnCalendar"]; //AddOn calendar
            }
            catch
            {
                _olFolderCalendar_AddOnCalendar = calendars.Folders.Add("AddOnCalendar");
            }
            _olFolderCalendar = calendars; //Standard calendar 
        }

        private void InitMailBox()
        {
            _olFolderInbox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)_OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            _olFolderDeletedItems = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)_OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
        }


        void Item_Calendar_Add(object item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("------ Item_Calendar_Add() ----------------------------------------------");
            PrintImportantInfo(item);

        }

        public void Item_Calendar_Change(object item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("------ Item_Calendar_Change() ----------------------------------------------");
            PrintImportantInfo(item);


        }

        void Item_Calendar_Deleted()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("------ Item_Calendar_Deleted() ---------------------------------------------");
            object item = _olFolderDeletedItems.Items.GetLast();
            PrintImportantInfo(item);


        }

        void PrintImportantInfo(object item)
        {
            try
            {


                Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
                if (appointment != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("APPOINTMENTINFO_________________________________________________________");
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_Subject: " + appointment.Subject.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_MeetingStatus: " + appointment.MeetingStatus.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_ResponseStatus: " + appointment.ResponseStatus.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_GlobalAppointmentID: " + appointment.GlobalAppointmentID.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_Time: " + appointment.Start.ToString() + " - " + appointment.End.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_Organizer: " + appointment.GetOrganizer().Address.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   A_Organizer: " + appointment.Organizer);
                    if (appointment.Location != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_Location: " + appointment.Location.ToString());
                }
                Outlook.MeetingItem meeting = item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
                if (meeting != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("MEETINGINFO_____________________________________________________________");

                    Debug.WriteLine("   M_Subject: " + meeting.Subject.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   M_MessageClass: " + meeting.MessageClass.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine("   M_SenderEmailAddress: " + meeting.SenderEmailAddress.ToString());
                    appointment = meeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(false);
                    if (appointment != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("APPOINTMENTINFO_________________________________________________________");
                        appointment.Save();
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_Subject: " + appointment.Subject.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_MeetingStatus: " + appointment.MeetingStatus.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_ResponseStatus: " + appointment.ResponseStatus.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_GlobalAppointmentID: " + appointment.GlobalAppointmentID.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_Time: " + appointment.Start.ToString() + " - " + appointment.End.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_Organizer: " + appointment.GetOrganizer().Address.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("   A_Organizer: " + appointment.Organizer.ToString());
                        if (appointment.Location != null)
                            Debug.WriteLine("   A_Location: " + appointment.Location.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing each action within a separate thread?

```
bool monitoring = false;
while (true)
{
   if (!monitoring) //Start monitoring or restart monitoring
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("start");
      ThisAddIn_Startup();
      monitoring = true;
   }
   Process[] outlook;
   new Thread(() => {
     outlook = Process.GetProcessesByName("blabla");
   }.Start();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}


private void ThisAddIn_Startup()
{
   _OutlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();

   //Link Inbodx Events
   _olFolderInbox.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);

   //Link Calendar Events
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Add);
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Change);
   _olFolderCalendar.Items.ItemRemove += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(Item_Calendar_Deleted);
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but didn't work. I just don't understand how this could influence this???

Comment: Because they both share the same therefore have to wait for one another to finish before continuing

Comment: I'm sorry I am stuck. I posted the hole (simplified) code above under EDIT. What are the same?